# How to SSR vue 3 in php?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to know how to **server side render vue 3 code inside laravel 8 (with webpack)** project.

All info I managed to get was on vue 2.5 like how to do it with v8 and other plugins like here https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering/issues/83

Comment: See if you can get https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering to work

Comment: There is no way to SSR a JS framework with PHP (I mean, without the need of NodeJS). You are asking something similar like "I have this X frontend language, and I want it to have it SSR by Y language that does not understand anything nor knows X, how can I do it ?"

Comment: @apokryfos I'll try it!

Comment: @matiaslauriti nodejs is ok as long as It is made to work on it's own in php as V8. I don't know much how that js ssr in php works but I know that it was possible with vue 2.5. So what I mean with "How to SSR vue 3 in php" is something with some external toool and not directly write js in php. Just exploring how to do it because I know it was possible on previous version

Comment: @matiaslauriti Typically what you'd do in that case is to call nodejs via a `shell_exec` or something and output the result somewhere where PHP can read it so technically PHP can't do it but that does not necessarily mean it can't be done

Comment: @apokryfos It can't be done, in the way that PHP will not be able to do anything if you can't call `shell_exec` and have that language there what will give you something back, you could `shell_exec` anything, but this is just a `layer`, not the resolver itself.

Comment: @LizardDerad Good luck with your search ! I never thought about this, but as you stated, PHP cannot do anything, it will be just a layer (in the best case scenario). I never heard or saw PHP serving like this, in all my professional career, I saw all the time NodeJS and direct communication with your framework, never PHP, or C# (ASP), or anything like that in the middle.

Comment: @matiaslauriti There is a way to do it without Node.js. Check https://github.com/phpv8/v8js

Answer (score 2):

The real answer to your question is that if you want to do SSR using vanilla PHP or Laravel, you would use your controller to modify the base file (like what may be your current index.html file) prior to the user receiving it. This isn't recommended and complicates things a bit. If you're using vanilla Laravel or PHP, you shouldn't need to do this anyway since blade files are already rendered by the server natively.

If you're making a SPA or web app and not using blade files, your SSR now has nothing to do with PHP and everything to do with your JS framework.

Vue.js has a tutorial on how to do SSR here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html

And I found an example package here:

https://github.com/acoshift/vuejs-ssr-example

And if you're interested in switching to React, Nextjs handles this out of the gates with zero setup:

https://nextjs.org/

It plays nicely with Laravel Sanctum and there's packages available to handle that quickly as well.

Comment: Official SSR package for Vue 3: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/server-renderer